# animate image property Left

Tags: jquery, html, css

OnClick event of img:

```
$(obj).animate({"left": "-=40px"},"slow");
$(obj).animate({"height":"600px","width":"320px"},30);
```

I want to animate width and height of image. Also, I am moving my image left by -40px. Afterwards again on the click event I want to bring back image to original size and position. I have tried this, but animate left is taking image to very left not to original place.

```
$(obj).animate({"Right": "+=40px"},"slow");
$(obj).animate({"height":"449px","width":"249px","left":"-20px"},30);
```

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create an example of your code, so it is easier for us to provide the correct anwser for you

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(obj).animate({"height":"449px","width":"249px","left":"-20px"},30);
```

to

```
$(obj).animate({"height":"449px","width":"249px","left":"-=20px"},30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops... I noticed that `"left":"-20px"` was extra in

```
$(obj).animate({"height":"449px","width":"249px","left":"-20px"},30);
```

After removing it the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$(obj).animate({"Right": "+=40px"},"slow");
```

to:

```
$(obj).animate({"left": "+=40px"},"slow");
```

since when you use `"Right": "+=40px"`, again your `obj` will move to the left `40px`

Comment: this is moving image to  the right side of page .. image is not going back to original position

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem?